# PayPal button: How to return a specified value when a payment is successful?

Tags: php, button, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment

I'm trying to add a PayPal "pay now" type of button, which redirects users to make a payment. But after that's done, how would my database and program know if a payment was successful, and which thing was paid for?

I need PayPal to take a simple id variable, and return it to a specified page only after a payment happens. I think if PayPal can simply hold my "item_id" variable, it would be enough.

On my payments page:

```
<?php
$item_id = $item["id"];
?>
<td>
<!-- code from PayPal: -->
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="RZ3N8DZLEYN5L">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0"    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</td>
```

On the payment_complete page:

```
<?php
if(isset($item_id)){
    $query  = "UPDATE items SET status = 'paid' WHERE id = {$item_id}";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    redirect_to("paywalled_page.php");
}else{
    redirect_to("payments.php");
}
?>
```

At PayPal, on the button creation page, under "advanced features" it looks like it lets me type a variable to return to a specified URL, but even if I got that to work I don't think a hardcoded "$paid = true" would be enough.

Comment: You should look into the PayPal IPN, this isn't it. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the "custom" passthrough variable might do it

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/